# Capitalizing the first letter of every word

Tags: javascript

for some reason "I'm a little tea pot" returns "i'm
 a little tea pot". I want it to be "I'm A Little Tea Pot". I was able to make the string all lowercase using .toLowerCase(), but my code for some reason won't capitalize the first letter of every word. Anyone know why?

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    for (i = 0; i > str.length; i++){
        str = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }

    return str.join(" ");
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Comment: Replace i > str.length by i < str.length

Comment: You aren't actually ever iterating through the string as your condition within your `for` loop is going to immediately fail. You need to switch it from `i > str.length` to `i < str.length`.

Comment: Because you are reassigning the value of `str` in your loop, you won't iterate all the words in the original array. You'll need to store the corrected words in a different variable.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var str_arr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < str_arr.length; i++){
    str_arr[i] = str_arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+(str_arr[i].substr(1));
  }
  return str_arr.join(" ");
}
titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this line loud

```
str = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
```

"Take word number `i` from the array `str`, take its first character, covert it to upper case and assign it to `str`". The last part will overwrite the array `str`

Furthermore your for condition is wrong

Try this

```
var words = [];
for(i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
   words[i] = str[i];
   words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].substring(1);
}
return words.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "i'm a little tea pot";

function titleCaseChange(s)
{
    return s.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(t){
      return t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
var res = titleCaseChange(str);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code never enters your inner loop.

```
for (i = 0; i > str.length; i++)
```

Should be

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mix up with `>` and `<`, because you are reassigning the value of str in your loop, you won't iterate all the words in the original array and your attempt to call `str.join()` will fail. You'll need to store the corrected words in a different variable and you'll need to add the remaining characters after the first one is capitalized.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
    var strArry = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var strTemp = [];  // Adjusted strings will go here

    for (i = 0; i < strArry.length; i++){
        // Capitalized the first letter of the word and add the remaining letters of the word
        // Then, add the corrected word to the new array
        strTemp.push(strArry[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + strArry[i].substr(1,strArry[i].length));
    }

    // Put spaces between the array elements
    return strTemp.join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
titleCase= function(inputString){
inputString = inputString.toLowerCase().split(" ");
var finalString = [];
for(i=0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
   finalString[i] = inputString[i];
   finalString[i] = finalString[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + finalString[i].substring(1);
}
return finalString.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = titleCase('hello world, weather is awesome!!')"> titleCase('hello world, weather is awesome!!')</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` loops are a code smell :)

```js
const capWord = word => word ? word.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1) : '';
const capSentence = sentence => sentence.split(/\s+/).map(capWord).join(' ');
const result = capSentence('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog');

console.log(result);
```